# React and Redux toolkit - reject after promise

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a React Native app. I have a signup screen which has a button, onclick:

```js
const handleClick = (country: string, number: string): void => {
    dispatch(registerUser({ country, number }))
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("here", response);
        navigation.navigate(AuthRoutes.Confirm);
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log('rejected', e);
      });
  };
```

The registerUser function:

```js
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/register',
    async ({ country, number }: loginDataType, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await bdzApi.post('/register', { country, number });
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return rejectWithValue(err.message);
        }
    },
);
```

I have one of my `extraReducers` that is indeed called, proving that it's effectively rejected.

```
.addCase(registerUser.rejected, (state, {meta,payload,error }) => {
    state.loginState = 'denied';
    console.log(`nope : ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
})
```

But the signup component gets processed normally, logging "here" and navigating to the Confirm screen. Why is that?

Comment: Can you show the  `rejectWithValue`? You probably need to _throw_ the error instead of _returning_ it.

Comment: @Yousaf well, it's destructured in the args from thunkAPI, as you can see `{ rejectWithValue }` - it's a function from redux toolkit. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator

Comment: I am not aware of the redux-toolkit but my guess is that _returning_ a value from the `catch` block is [implicitly fulfilling the promise](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/common-promise-anti-patterns#converting-promise-rejection-in-to-fulfilment) returned by the wrapper function.

Comment: You're completely right. If I simply stop returning and just write `rejectWithValue(err.message);`, the error is catched in the component. Interestingly enough, then, it's the reducer that misbehave - it calls the `registerUser.fulfilled` reducer instead of the `registerUser.rejected` that is actually called when I'm returning the thing!

Comment: @JeremyBelolo how did you solve this? I am currently facing this issue. it returns fulfil when it should reject, reject when it should fulfil.

Comment: @emekaokoli the accepted answer is good. You should check it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A thunk created with `createAsyncThunk` will always resolve but if you want to catch it in the function that dispatches the thunk you have to use [unwrapResults](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results).

> The thunks generated by createAsyncThunk will always return a resolved promise with either the fulfilled action object or rejected action object inside, as appropriate.
>
> The calling logic may wish to treat these actions as if they were the original promise contents. Redux Toolkit exports an unwrapResult function that can be used to extract the payload of a fulfilled action or to throw either the error or, if available, payload created by rejectWithValue from a rejected action:

```
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

// in the component
const onClick = () => {
  dispatch(fetchUserById(userId))
    .then(unwrapResult)
    .then(originalPromiseResult => {})
    .catch(rejectedValueOrSerializedError => {})
}
```